# Swift prepare for Segue: How to know If a button or a table row initiated Segue

Tags: ios, swift, segue

This is my code. I'm trying to perform a segue. I have a bar button item as well as a table with rows performing the same segue. I want to know when the button is clicked and when a particular row.

The following code works for a button but not for the rows of the table

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    activePlaceRow = indexPath.row

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "toMap", sender: nil)

}


override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "toMap"
    {
        let mapViewController = segue.destination as! ViewController

        if let senderObject = sender
        {
            if (senderObject as! UIBarButtonItem).tag == 1
            {

                mapViewController.activePlaceRow = -2
            }
            else
            {
                mapViewController.activePlaceRow = activePlaceRow
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pass the index path as `sender`

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "toMap", sender: indexPath)

}


override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "toMap"
    {
        let mapViewController = segue.destination as! ViewController

        if let buttonItem = sender as? UIBarButtonItem, buttomItem.tag == 1 {
            mapViewController.activePlaceRow = -2
        }
        else if let indexPath = sender as? IndexPath {
            mapViewController.activePlaceRow = indexPath.row
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is add a property to your `UIViewController`

`var isSegueFromCell:Bool = false`

In your `didSelectRowAt` method you can assign this value as `true`. Then, when your `prepareForSegue` method gets called, you check:

```
if isSegueFromCell {

    print("SEGUE FROM TABLE VIEW")
}
else {
    print("SEGUE FROM BUTTON")
}
```

**OR**

When you call `performSegue` you can pass in a `Bool` indicating `true` if being called from your `didSelectRow` method

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "YourSegueID", sender: true)
```

Then detect this in your `prepareForSegue` method

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
if let value = sender as? Bool {
        if value {
            print("FROM TABLE VIEW ROW")
        } else {
            print("FROM BUTTON")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One easy thing to do is to check `indexPathForSelectedRow` or `indexPathsForSelectedRows`.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

if segue.identifier == "toMap"
{
    let mapViewController = segue.destination as! ViewController

    if let senderObject = sender
    {
        if (senderObject as! UIBarButtonItem).tag == 1
        {

            mapViewController.activePlaceRow = -2
        }
        else
        {
            mapViewController.activePlaceRow = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
        }
    }

}
```

No need for the `activePlaceRow` this way. You can also create a segue in the storyboard by right clicking on the cell and dragging to the view controller, and then delete your `didSelectRow` implementation.